# Combining generic "one", "he" or "they" in a convoluted sentence

Tags: pronouns, grammaticality-in-context, genderless-pronouns

What is **the best** and what is **acceptable** from the following sentences?

1. If one finds oneself in a situation where one's own life is at stake, one should think of oneself first.
2. If one finds himself in a sitation where his own life is at stake, he should think of himself first.
3. If one finds themselves in a situation where their own life is at stake, one should think of themselves first.

Comment: I believe that American sources traditionally follow _one_ with _he_ (or _she_) - I don't know if they have updated it to _they_. British English traditionally repeats _one_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Simple examples like the one you linked can be found over the web, however the 1st one I would infer as the most grammatical, in their advice, sounds super loaded to me, so I wondered about which alternative would a native speaker prefer. The 3rd variant is what I would think as the 2nd most grammatical but the changing of plural pronoun and singular meaning still sounded too loaded to me. So the generic "he" sounds the most understandable but I know it's controversial and I've been discouraged from combining it with "one" so unfortunately, the answer doesn't help me.

Comment: Your own comment there refers to "the 2nd most grammatical", so obviously you recognise that there are *degrees* of "correctness" in such matters. And as Colin correctly points out (I did enough checking with NGrams to convince myself of *that*) AmE and BrE have a significant usage difference here. I'm a Brit, but I quite naturally switch to ***he*** to avoid "unnaturally" repeating ***one*** and its variants too often, but switching to ***she*** just sounds like a terrible "PC affectation" (far worse than feminising God! :) But if you think that's "controversial", you don't have to copy me!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Many thanks, I didn't have much idea abou the degree of controversiality, it's true it's only logical to use "one" when you don't want to specify the gender. I'm not a fan of politicizing language because I think pointing out the connotations can oftentimes strengthen them but God's gender is a great example of a case where it truly shifts the perception. I think the most logical would be to call God "it" as a bodiless abtract superhuman entity. :)

Comment: It's all a minefield! I see from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she%27s+the+chairman+of%2Cshe%27s+the+chairwoman+of%2Cshe%27s+the+chair+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20%27s%20the%20chairman%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20%27s%20the%20chair%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cshe%20's%20the%20chairman%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20's%20the%20chair%20of%3B%2Cc0) that *she's the **chair** of [some organisation]* has recently overtaken (sexist?! :) ***chairman***. But apparently ***chairwoman*** has made very little headway.

Answer (score 4):

Your first version is obviously correct grammatically, and, traditionally in the U.S., the second is as well. The third may be on its way to becoming correct, perhaps mandatory, in the U.S.

I must admit that I find them all awkward.

> If your life is at stake, think of yourself first.

strikes me as far more natural.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the complete rewrite.